# Store dbcc checkdb result to a file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to run dbcc checkdb on weekly basis and wanted to store that result in a .txt file. Please let me know how could I export the data from ssms to txt file.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the script into .sql file and execute it using [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) utility.

for example: `exec xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -i "D:\ChdbQuery.sql" -o "D:\dbcheckpubs.txt"'`

only need  to change path, server name & authentication appropriately